# MACRO error when using the switch statement

Tags: c, macros, switch-statement

Hey take a look at the code:

```
#define SUFFIX(n)  (switch(n)                                               \
                   {                                                        \
                        case 1: printf("st\n");                             \
                        break;                                              \
                                                                            \
                        case 2: printf("nd\n");                             \
                        break;                                              \
                                                                            \
                        case 3: printf("rd\n");                             \
                        break;                                              \
                   }                                                        \
                   )
```

calling the above macro in main:

```
int main()
{
    printf("%s", suffix(1));
}
```

But when I call this I get a error message:

```
expected expression before switch
```

But what expression am I missing?

Comment: I feel you're confusing expressions and statements and GNU compound expressions...

Comment: You want a function, not a macro.

Comment: What will happen If i use macros. I think functio overheads kill a bit of time every time its called so why not macros? Just asking BTW

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're trying to do won't work. `switch` is a statement but `printf` requires an expression.

**Option 1:**

Remove the brackets `()` from your `#define` and simply say `SUFFIX(1)` without the `printf`.

```
#define SUFFIX(n)  switch(n)                                               \
                   { case 1: printf("st\n"); break;                        \
                     case 2: printf("nd\n"); break;                        \
                     case 3: printf("rd\n"); break;                        \
                   }
int main()
{
    SUFFIX(1);
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
#define SUFFIX(n) ( n == 1 ? "st" : (n == 2 ? "nd" : (n == 3 ? "rd" : "")) )
int main()
{
  printf("%s", SUFFIX(1));
}
```

**Option 3 and 4:**

Make one of the above a function. The first returns `void`, the second returns `char *`.

Comment: You must be C god, Thanks a lot, How silly of me to make this mistake!

Comment: BTW should I use this macro or a function?

Comment: @user1971996 Functions add a *tiny* bit of overhead but you can't step into macros when debugging, they increase your code size, can make your code a bit messy and **don't do type checking** (just off the top of my head). Both have advantages and disadvantages (with functions looking slightly better). So it's up to your really.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used macros BTW.